# Opus 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 w/ preinstalled Opus 0.5.2

Tags: dependencies, versions

I'd like to compile Qt (5.15.2), which uses the latest opus coded (1.3.1). Ubuntu 18.04 comes w/ previous version 0.5.2. Can I simply build new version to /usr/local? I don't want to mess my OS..

Comment: Really? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libopus-dev Will [Qt 5.9.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/qtbase-opensource-src) be ok for you?

Comment: Yes, really.. The package from your link is an old version and I need the latest, because QWebEngine is too old in Qt 5.9.5. Anyway, here is my answer: Prebuilt package contains libopus.so.0.5.2 and the latest version 1.3.1 produces libopus.so.0.8.x. Installing different package versions w/ the same major number (in this case 0) can cause dependency hell, so my answer is NO..

Comment: Please post your answer, in the answer section, ***not*** the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Prebuilt package contains libopus.so.0.5.2 and the latest version 1.3.1 produces libopus.so.0.8.x. Installing different package versions w/ the same major number (in this case 0) can cause dependency hell, so the answer is NO.